telegram tdLib: getting comments to posts in a channel
How can I get all comments to a post in a channel? to get posts i use the method getChatHistory, and I see group id on some messages like:
reply_info=#<TD::Types::MessageReplyInfo reply_count=18 recent_replier_ids=[#<TD::Types::MessageSender::Chat chat_id=-1001807026238>

then by chat_id I can get all comments, but how to get comments separately for a specific post in the channel? do official ios and android clients use tdLib? in them I see a comment counter for each post, when I click on it, only comments for the desired post are displayed

p.s. I use gem tdlib-ruby

You must use the method getMessageThread for this. Check the flag can_get_message_thread from getMessageProperties to know whether a channel post has comments.
